# Containers - Writing to Windows Event log from Containers throwing error "Inaccessible logs"

Tags: windows, containers, console-application, event-log

I am running a .net core (6.1) console application in **containers**. When it tries to write to the Windows Event log, it throws this error

> The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be
> searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security, State.

Here is the code:

```
string name = "My Console App";
try
{
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists(name))
    {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(name, "Application");
    }

    EventLog.WriteEntry(name, pMessage, pEvntType);
}
catch (SecurityException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I have looked at a similar issues but they are all talking about IIS. Any help